# use exec with a command typed from keyboard

Tags: c, exec, system-calls, pid

I create an array of strings to put attributes to the command (e.g. `ls -l`), but `exec` command wants an array of chars, how can i resolve it? this code should create a child which execute a command chosen by input.. I have even some problems with the `wait()` when `pid != 0`.. Can you help me out to finish it? Thank you a lot.

```
int main(void) {

        char array[100];
        char character;
        int i = 0;
        char* point;
        int j = 0;

        printf ("Digit a string");
        printf ("\n");
        do {
            character = getchar();
            array[i] = character;
            i++;
        }
        while (character != '\n');
        array[i-1] = '\0';
        i = 0;

        char* string[100];

        char *word = strtok(array, " .");
        while (word != NULL) {
            printf("%s\n", word);
            string[j] = word;
            word = strtok(NULL, " .");

        }

        printf ("\n");  

    pid_t  pid;
    pid = fork();

        if (pid == -1) {

        perror("");

    }else if (pid == 0) {

        if (execlp(string, NULL) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */

                    exit(1);
            }
      else {

        //.. wait until the child ends
        wait(pid);



      }
   }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try reading the manpage for `wait()`? That should easily answer part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your big issue is you are not using `execlp` correctly.  `execlp` takes a variable number of arguments that are the arguments passed to the program.  It is expected to work like this:

```
execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
```

What you have is an array of arguments so you want to use one of the `v` variants of exec.  You can find all the variants [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp).  So what you want to do is something more like this:

```
execvp(string[0], string);
```

Note that the command itself is one of the arguments as in both examples.  Another issue with your program is you are not incrementing `j` in your loop where you are using `strtok`.  Also note that for `execvp` the last element of the array should be `NULL` so exec knows what it has found the last argument.  One final thing is that you do not have to check the return value of any of the `exec` functions.  If `exec` returned that means there was an error, otherwise it never returns.  `errno` is set when `exec` fails so you can check that.  For completeness find, sections of corrected code below with comments:

```
char *word = strtok(array, " .");
j = 0;
while (word != NULL) {
  printf("%s\n", word);
  string[j++] = word; // Increment j
  word = strtok(NULL, " .");
}
string[j] = NULL; // Make sure the array is NULL terminated
```

And where you call `exec`

```
execvp(string[0], string); // You most likely want execvp, execv would work as 
                           // well but that takes an entire path and not a filename
fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec"); // If the program reached this point we know exec failed
exit(1);
```

Let me explain he comment at `execvp` in greater detail.  The `exec` variants with a `p` in their name take a filename instead of a path.  These variants will mimic how a shell works and use the `PATH` environment variable to look for the binary.  Therefore if you do something like `execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);` it will work assuming you have `ls` in one of the folders specified by `PATH`.  If you do `execl("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);`  (not the lack of a `p`) it will fail as `"ls"` is not a valid path; it would have to be something like `"/usr/bin/ls"` instead.  Which version you want, something that takes a filename or a file path, depends on your application.

Comment: thank you so much esm! now the code works perfectly!